# Is there a definitive reference for Windows shortcuts keys?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a definitive reference of all of the Windows shortcut keys along with which operating systems they apply to?

For example, we all know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, but I've met quite a few people that don't know about <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to lock the computer in Windows XP and up.

Comment: None of the answers so far list the new Windows 7 keyboard shortcuts, such as Win+Up to maximize the current window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I doubt there's a full one anywhere, since programs can make up their own, but [this Microsoft one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) is pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301583) a rather long list from the Microsoft support website for Windows XP.