# Keyboard shortcut / navigation references

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I use the mouse much too freely, and my wrists are not thanking me for it. I have been meaning to try and use the keyboard more as my sole means of navigating Windows, but I am having trouble sticking with it because when I need to do something and I cannot find the right shortcut, I grab the mouse and forget to let go of it again.

Personally, the main software that I need keyboard reference sheets for would be:

- Firefox
- Thunderbird
- Visual Studio
- Windows itself

But **I would encourage more general inclusion of shortcut references** in the answers in case anyone else tries to make the same transition I am attempting ;)

What I am looking for is reference material that is as *comprehensive as possible* so that over time I can hopefully learn to do everything with the keyboard and spare my wrists. Bonus points for *references that can be printed* in a reasonable size so I can keep them next to my machine in hardcopy.

I know there is an answer for Windows already: [Is there a definitive reference for Windows shortcuts keys?](https://superuser.com/questions/1371/is-there-a-definitive-reference-for-windows-shortcuts-keys), but I am leaving it in my question in case anyone has a better printable alternative.

Comment: Please make this a community wiki.

Comment: Switched it over to CW. Topics like this which are open to discussions or lists (i.e. most items that don't have a "correct" answer) should generally be CW.

Comment: I should have also said that this probably should have been separated into requests for keyboard shortcuts for the different software programs.

Comment: Thanks for the switch to CW... I honestly keep forgetting to tick the little box... start of "This should be a CW", but then after I add tags, it completely slips my mind. Should the CW selection perhaps be a bit more prominently visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of 'em.

- [Firefox](http://lesliefranke.com/files/reference/firefoxcheatsheet.html)
- [Thunderbird](http://lesliefranke.com/files/reference/thunderbirdcheatsheet.html)
- [Visual Studio (not optimized for paper)](http://www.dev102.com/vs-cheatsheet/)
- [Windows XP (general keyboard shortcuts, PDF-file)](http://websupportblog.files.wordpress.com/2006/10/keyboard-shortcuts-trifold.pdf)

Comment: Had hoped for a few more people with helpful ones, but I guess I'll just create new specific questions when I run into more programs. Your answer covers my immediate question tho ;)