# Other than home/end, are there standard keyboard shortcuts to go to the begin/end of a line of text in Windows apps?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a definitive reference for Windows shortcuts keys?](https://superuser.com/questions/1371/is-there-a-definitive-reference-for-windows-shortcuts-keys)

I am trying to re-train my fingers to avoid the use of home/end since those are not available on Mac keyboards. I have to use both Mac and Windows.

So, other than home/end, are there standard keyboard shortcuts to go to the begin/end of a line of text in Windows apps?

Comment: If it isn't a laptop, then you could simply replace your keyboard.  Almost any standard USB keyboard will work fine with an iMac, Mac mini, or Mac Pro.

Comment: That's the issue, I'm usually on the laptop. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an [article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts), not really. The Mac equivalents of <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd> are <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in Windows is "select all" of course. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is generally only to jump to the address bar in a browser. In Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> jumps words.